# Оптимизация картинок для PageSpeed Insights средствами CentOS

Tags: оптимизация, изображения, оптимизация-сайтов, pagespeed-insights, поисковая-оптимизация

Есть сайт интернет магазина. Тестирую главную страницу инструментом [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

Результат

1. Для мобильных сайтов:
   Page Speed Unavailable
   Оптимизация Medium 61 / 100
   [image: Для мобильных сайтов]
2. Для компьютеров:
   Page Speed Unavailable
   Оптимизация Low 29 / 100
   [image: Для компьютеров]

Вопрос стоит в оптимизации картинок и последующей проверкой инструментом google.
Знаю, что ниже в окне результатов есть ссылка на файл с оптимизированными картинки google. Я пробовал их загружать на сайт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Проблема в следующем:**

1. Архив с оптимизированными картинки не содержит структуру. Получается
   их вручную нужно загружать.
2. Поменяв картинку на оптимизированную картинку от google, я проверял. Не все картинки загруженные с архива проходят тест.
3. Некоторые картинки из архива в пикселях

**Видел рекомендации в интернете:**

1. Обычная картинка должна весить не больше - максимум 60 кб.
2. Большая картинка (детальная картинка, картинка слайдера) - максимум 120 кб.

Оптимизировал так же с помощью Caesium. Эта единственная программа, которую я нашел из бесплатных и сохраняющих структуру.

**Проблема Caesium:**

1. Некоторые картинки после оптимизации в пикселях

**Самый лучший из мной найденных вариантов - вручную оптимизировать картинку используя онлайн сервис.**

**Вопрос.
Как оптимизировать?**

Comment: Фотошоп, ctrl+alt+shift+s (save for web)

Comment: @nicolaa, вопрос в массовой оптимизации изображений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Оптимизировать картинки на сервере.**

GooglePageSpeed - требует уменьшения размер картинок, притом достаточно настойчиво.
Так же это действительно помогает снизить нагрузку на сайт и у увеличить скорость его загрузки.

> **Важно!** Все описанные действия выполнялись на выделенном сервере.
>
> - Установлена CentOS 7.x
> - В качестве CMS используется 1C-Bitrix

Для сжатия понадобится  две утилиты `jpegoptim` - она будет оптимизировать jpg ну и png  займется `optipng`.

Для начала необходимо их установить:

```
sudo yum install jpegoptim optipng -y
```

Теперь остается только сжать картинки до приемлемого качества.

```
find /home/bitrix/ext_www/example.com/{upload/resize_cache,upload/iblock/,local}/ -type f -regex ".*\(jpg\|jpeg\|JPG\|JPEG\)" -exec jpegoptim --preserve --preserve-perms --max=85 {} \;  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

И повторяем с png:

```
find /home/bitrix/ext_www/example.com/{upload/resize_cache,upload/iblock/,local}/ -type f -regex ".*\(png\|PNG\)" -print -exec optipng -o5 -quiet -keep -preserve {} \;
```

На этом всё, это должно быть достаточно для сжатия картинок.

**Результат оптимизации:**
[image: После оптимизации на мобильном]
[image: После оптимизации на компьютере]

Answer (score 1):

Для анализа скорости загрузки на реальном мобильном устройстве вы можете использовать инструмент **[WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/)**. На этом инструменте основан инструмент Гугл **[Test your mobile speed](https://testmysite.withgoogle.com/intl/ru-ru)** и Гугл рекомендует применять этот инструмент.

Для анализа ваших веб-страниц выберите наиболее старое устройство из предлагаемого списка. Я обычно выбираю iPhone 5c. Это связано с тем что многие регионы, страны и просто отдельные места могут иметь недостаточно четкий сигнал или даже не иметь соединения 4G. После проведения анализа какой-то вашей веб-страницы, вы увидите три окна Waterfall с анализом загрузки ресурсов веб-страницы. Выберите то окно, которое имеет наиболее медленное время загрузки и щелкните на нем. Вам откроется список ресурсов анализируемой веб-страницы. Наиболее длинные бары являются, соответственно, наиболее критичными для скорости загрузки. Анализируйте и оптимизируйте эти ресурсы. Для этого вы можете использовать следующие руководства Гугл:

- **[Процесс визуализации](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/)** - изучите полный этот курс
- **[Отзывчивые изображения](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images)** - обратите здесь внимание на возможность использования элементов **[picture](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp)** и **[srcset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_srcset.asp)**. Также может быть полезным использование изображений с относительными размерами такими как **[vw](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)**.

Для изменения размеров ваших изображений вы можете использовать инструмент **[Photo editor online](https://pixlr.com/editor/)**.

Для сжатия ваших изображений вы можете использовать инструмент **[ImageOptim online](https://imageoptim.com/online)**.

Используя эти инструменты совместно с **[фреймворком АМП](https://www.ampproject.org/)** вы можете создавать веб-страницы которые загружаются до 3 секунд, как это и рекомендует Гугл, потому что для мобильных пользователей это максимальное время ожидания загрузки вызванной веб-страницы.

Comment: Инструмент Test your mobile speed, не работает. В поле для ввода указываю сайт, нажимаю на кнопку ввода (стрелка), ничего не происходит

Comment: Этот инструмент я указал вам только для идентификации WebPageTest: Технология WebPageTest.org  Используйте этот инструмент.